# Android there is some way for don't waste layout when orientation change?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application that have a `TableLayout` with 60 texviews.
The user can touch them and a `DialogActivity` start for take the text and background color of the clicked `TextView`.
But the app have a bug that some times all `TextView` take the color of the first inputed color **and inside of the code i haven't a loop that assign the color**.
I think that, the problem come from to the orientation of the screen (possible?).
Because the Activity that contain `TableLayout` is `landscape` and the `Dialog` is `portrait`.
Infact when the Dialog start behind it there is the Activity that change his orientation with the Dialog and all textviews change their color.
How can i avoid this bug?
Why this happend?

Acitivity landscape:

```
public class ActivitySetOrario extends ActionBarActivity {

//Static perch� cosi non perdo i dati inseriti in precedenza!
static int clickedTextViewId; // Declare TextView as class level member field

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_orario);

    MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    //Get all materie inside database
    List<Materia> materia = db.getAllMaterie();
    //change all TextView inputed from user
    if(materia.isEmpty()){
        //do nothing
    }else {
        for (Materia mat : materia) {
            //Change all the TextView with values stored inside the database
            TextView changedtextview = (TextView) findViewById(mat.getID());
            changedtextview.setText(mat.getMateria());
            changedtextview.setBackgroundColor(mat.getColor());
        }
    }


}//Fine oncreate

//Prende indietro la materia aggiunta dall'ActivityAddMateria
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result"); //Take the materia from Dialog
            int color = data.getIntExtra("color", 1); //Take the color from Dialog

            //Here i need to recognize row and column
            db.addMateria(new Materia(clickedTextViewId, result, color));

           TextView clickedtextView = (TextView) findViewById(clickedTextViewId); //(TextView) view;
           clickedtextView.setText(result);
           clickedtextView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Nessuna materia inserita
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_set_orario, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.draw_orario:
        //addMateria();
        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        db.deleteMateria();
        onStart();
        return true;
    case R.id.save_data_orario:
        //SERIALIZZO I DATI CHE DOVRA PRENDERE ActivityOrario
        backToOrario();
        finish();
        return true;     
    case R.id.exit_orario:
        //Torno alla schermata orario annullo ogni modifica NON SERIALIZZO
        backToOrario();
        finish();
        return true;     
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//Torna alla ActivityOrario
public void backToOrario(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityOrario.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void addMateria(View v){
    //To get ID of your TextView do this
    clickedTextViewId = v.getId();
    //StartActivityForResult perche mi aspetto la materia inserita dall'altra activity
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivitySetOrario.this, ActivityAddMateria.class);
    ActivitySetOrario.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
}
}
```

The Dialog portrait Activity:

```
public class ActivityAddMateria extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_materia);

    final Button exit_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_dialog_materia);
    exit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //No input
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            //Exit from Dialog
            finish();
        }
    });

    final Button accept_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_materia);
    accept_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Find EditText for take data
            EditText nome_materia = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nome_materia);
            //Put result into variable result that is send back
            String result = nome_materia.getText().toString();


            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.group1);
            int radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);

            Drawable background = radioButton.getBackground();
            if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                int color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result",result).putExtra("color",color);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            }
            // Exit to Dialog
            finish();
        }
    });

}
```

}

The xml of the first activity:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue_orario"
android:id="@+id/table">
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/dayrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Lun."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Mar."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Mer."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Gio."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ven."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sab."
        android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollorario"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/prima_riga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_orario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat11"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text=""/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat12"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat13"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat14"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat15"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mat16"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="addMateria"
                    android:background="@color/grigio_chiaro"
                    android:text="" />
            </TableRow>
            <!--TOO LONG THE XML I CUT IT THE OTHER ROW ARE THE SAME-->
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</TableLayout>
```

Some screenshoot:
[image: First item added]
[image: Dialog with normal Actvity behind]
[image: All Textviews changed! (not good)]
[image: The result that i want]

Comment: You need to add some code.

Comment: what do you need? The Activity and Dialog? or some xml too?

Comment: So there is only one orientation: that of the device. Unless you are requesting the orientation change (in your manifest) there is no orientation change occuring here! Furthermore, you are doing something much more complicated: instead of using a seperate activity (your dialog activity), just use a dialog in the same activity.

Comment: You should also not be calling onStart explicitly--that is a system callback for you, not something to call on your own (usually).

Comment: @AshtonEngberg yes i delete the onStart(), but it's not the problem.
So i can call the Dialog inside the same Activity? (i'm new with android and java i don't know that).
Yes i change orientation with the Manifest! But i see that when i call the DialogActvity the old activity behind change all TextViews background color!
You think that the problem occur because i call another activity for the Dialog?

Comment: Can you add two screenshots? Also your xml layout for the first activity.

Comment: Done, as you can see the first image it's normal, the second img show the Dialog with the normal Behind.
The 3 image it's wrong, all textviews had taked the red color!
The last image it's good, but if i change activity some times all textviews change their background and sometimes they return fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74455/discussion-between-ashton-engberg-and-dario).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the ids of the textviews in your database: they can change between different compilations of your app. Which could be the culprit. However, the only way they're all being set is in the for loop: you should verify your database is correct and verify that loop is not running every time.

Comment: i see that the bug occur when i change activity it's a problem due too activity...it's possible?